# Short term time perception affect long term time perception?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, time

It is known that attending to time (i.e. looking at duration) expands subjective time. So if I want to do something for 20 minutes and look at my watch, this would increase my subjective time perception. Let's say that I have a timer that goes off every 10 minutes. I predict that a day would seem much longer.

- Would doing this for 1 week make the week seem longer?
- More generally, is it possible for short term time perception to affect long term time perception?

I know that time perception really is both a prospective and retrospective judgement. Time may feel like its passing slowly. But looking back on it, it may seem to have passed quickly. It seems that many mental disorders are fundamentally disorders in time perception.

Comment: *It seems that many mental disorders are fundamentally disorders in time perception* -- This statement feels subjective and out of place to me. Is it important to the question or can it be removed?

Comment: @JoshGitlin: I should have said that David Eagleman noted this.

Comment: @guest43434 a citation for where he said this and what this has to do with the rest of your question would be appreciated